# Is it possible to restrict "SHOW ROLES" in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Would like to know if there is any way in which to restrict a user seeing all the roles in an account by using "SHOW ROLES" command.

In the documentation it is mentioned "Snowflake allows users to list roles;" (source: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-roles.html), but it is not clear if this is the case always and can not be restricted.

Such a feature (restricting the "SHOW ROLES") would be useful if some roles contain information that should not be known by all users (ofc, a workaround is to use some hash for sensitive roles names).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, "Snowflake allows users to list roles" and it's not possible to restrict it for now.